# jQuery form submit a multidimensional array - Ajax/Php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i created two quite similar form, using jquery to make an Ajax/Php request. The only difference is that the first form send an array and get in response a multidimensional array, the second form send a multidimensional array and get another multidimensional array.

That's the jQuery request of the 1st Form

```
     $('#myFirstformid').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        var ajaxArray = new Array();
        ajaxArray.push(data1);
        ajaxArray.push(data2);
        ajaxArray.push(data3);

        var ajaxData = { ajaxArray: JSON.stringify(ajaxArray) };        
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../form-response-first-form.php',
                data: ajaxData,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $.each(data, function(index, element){
      //...do something...
                        });
                }
         });
     });
```

That's the php file of the 1st Form:

```
<?php
class ajax {
        function calc() {
                $ajaxArray = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['ajaxArray']));

                $data1 = $ajaxArray['0'];
                $data2 = $ajaxArray['1'];
                $data3 = $ajaxArray['2'];
                 //Array da ritornare al form
                $returnAjax = array();

                /*
                ...make some operation and push data in returnAjax...

                  */    

                return json_encode($returnAjax);
        }
} 
$ajax = new ajax;
echo $ajax->calc();
?>
```

Here the jQuery request of the 2nd Form:

```
    $('#mySecondformid').submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

 //Create the multidimensional array to send by getting value from the rows of the table
                var ajaxArray = $( "#preview tbody tr" ).map( function(){
                var tds = $(this).find( "td" ); 
                return {
                    data1: tds.eq(0).html(),
                    data2: tds.eq(1).html(),
                    data3: tds.eq(2).html()        
                };
            }).get();

                var ajaxData = { ajaxArray: JSON.stringify(ajaxArray) };        
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '../form-response-second-form.php',
                    data: ajaxData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            $.each(data, function(index, element){

                //...do something...
                            });
                    }
                });
            });
```

And here the php file for the 2nd:

```
<?php
class ajax {
         function calc() {
                $ajaxArray = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['ajaxArray']));
                //Array da ritornare al form
                $returnAjax = array();
                foreach ($ajaxArray as $value){
//...make some operation foreach subarray and push data in returnAjax...
                        }
             return json_encode($returnAjax);
         }
}

$ajax = new ajax;
echo $ajax->calc();
?>
```

I can't understand why the first form work right, but the second don't.

It seems there is no response from server cause there is nothing in the console log.
Thanks in advance

*EDIT

@SAM I have make a test and now I'm sure that the request to server is correct, and I get an empty response.

With another test I manually added the multidimensional array inside the php file, and the logic of the PHP is right. That's the array

```
 <?php    $ajaxArray = array( 
                                    0 => array(from => "01/01/2010",
                                               to => "01/01/2011",
                                               type => "Credit",
                                               amount => 10000.00
                                                ),
                                    1 => array( from => "01/01/2011",
                                                to => "01/01/2012",
                                                type => "Debit",
                                                amount => 200.00),
                                    2 => array( from => "01/01/2012",
                                                to => "01/01/2013",
                                                type => "Debit",
                                                amount => 100.00),
                                    3 => array( from => "01/01/2013",
                                                to => "23/04/2014",
                                                type => "Debit",
                                                amount => 100.00)
            );
    ?>
```

So the only thing I think could be wrong is that the jQuery code don't create the right multidimensional array. The multidimensional array is created by getting values from table, look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6q8cS/6/

Comment: Hey, First check whether 'ajaxData' in the second form has a value, if is there, ensure, it is a proper JSON object. secondly, since you have said, you are getting a empty response in console.log(), that means your request to server is correct and ensure you are getting HTTP status 200, then there must be some thing wrong in the logic of PHP

Comment: Hi, I know that there are values in ajaxArray (multidimensionale array), so if these code: "var ajaxData = { ajaxArray: JSON.stringify(ajaxArray) };" is correct, it meens that ajaxData has value properly formatted in JSON.. Finally I have said I get NO response at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess here...

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../form-response-second-form.php',
    data: ajaxData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) { }
```

It looks like you have a typo and so the `AJAX` call isn't hitting the right url. This would be consistent with seeing no response form the script in your dev tools.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did typo writing this post, but in the "real" form the url is correct